# EF Core In Memory Database not saving ICollection object column

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I have read that InMemory Database with EF Core has limitations and was considering moving to sqlite for development, however, I wanted to know if this behavior is a limitation of InMemory Database or if it's me. I have tried reading the documentation but can't find material explicitly mentioning this. I have the following:

```
    // Startup
    services.AddDbContext<StudentResultsContext>(opt =>
                                               opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("StudentResultsList"));
    // context
    public class StudentResultsContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentResultsContext(DbContextOptions<StudentResultsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<StudentResults> StudentResultsList { get; set; }
    }

    // classes
    public class StudentResults
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ExamScores> Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExamScores
    {
        public long ID{ get; set; }
        public long StudentId { get; set; }
        public Exam ExamType { get; set; }
        
        public double Score { get; set; }
    }
    // controller
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StudentResults>> PostStudentResults(StudentResults studentResults)
    {
        _context.StudentResultsList.Add(studentResults);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetStudentResults), new { id = studentResults.ID }, studentResults);
    }
```

`Results` is saved as null in the database up even though the return from post claims they were created, like so

`The post`
[image]

`What comes back from get`
[image]

Is this something I did or a problem with InMemory Databse?

Comment: You have to post all your classes not just one. We need to see how you are configuring the relations. And pls don't use images if you want to get some help.

Comment: I added the other class and the configuration in Startup. What's wrong with images? It was just to show how I appeared to post a ```StudentResults``` with ```Results``` but then getting that same ```StudentResults``` had null ```Results```

Comment: Try to remove id and studentId from your json

Comment: I tried removing those from the body of my post request and it resulted in about the same behavior- ```Results``` filled on post but still null on get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't do anything to load related data and thus you get `null` for `Results`.

Try to get saved entity with `context.StudentResultsList.Include(s => s.Results)`.

Check [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) for other strategies.

Comment: Perfect! Adding that to get accomplished what I was looking for. Thank you for linking relevant documentation for me to keep learning the framework as well.